# Arduino GPS Simulator: SoftwareSerial Issues

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, gps, rs232

For my project, i need my Arduino Uno to simulate a GPS. To do this, I need to:

- Generate a 5V Pulse once a second (no problem)
- Send a $GPRMC NMEA sentence with the current time over RS-232 (i've got an RS-232 shield)

The GPRMC message i need to send is the following:

$GPRMC,075832.293,A,4042.695,N,07400.796,W,,,080120,000.0,W*63

Where the first part is the time, and needs to change.
I basically implemented it as:

```
// Setup
String prefix = "$GPRMC,";
String gprmc  = "075832.293";
String suffix = ",A,4042.695,N,07400.796,W,,,080120,000.0,W*63";
String all = prefix + gprmc + suffix;
char* buff = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*all.length()+1);
```

Then, in the loop-code i update the time and want to send the message:

```
//...inside the condition that gets executed once a second
gprmc = String(gprmc.toFloat()+1);
all = prefix+gprmc+suffix;
all.toCharArray(buff, all.length()+1);
mySerial.write(buff);
```

I'm using an RS-232 shield, which shows me when a message is being sent by blinking an LED.
However, is only seems to work, if i shorten the all string, i.e.:
Works:

```
all = prefix+gprmc;
```

Does not work:

```
all = prefix+gprmc+suffix;
```

Is it possible that the message is just too long to send? Is there a way I can fix this? Because it's crucial to send the whole message.

Note: I'm currently working on an Arduino Uno, but I'm switching to an arduino Leonardo today. I currently have low memory available (77% used). could this add to the problem?

Thank you so much for your help!! :)

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? What did you expect and what actually happens?

Comment: On the RS-232 Shield, an LED blinks if a message is sent. By "doesn't work" i mean, no message is sent (led no blinking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, some comments about your code:

- Never use `String` unless it is absolutely unavoidable
- Unless you have a `free()` to balance your `malloc()` you will run out of memory almost immediately
- There is never any need to concatenate strings to send through serial like that.

Instead of what you are currently doing, just scrap the `String` usage and your `buf` variable completely.  There is no need to concatenate things together - serial sends data one character at a time, so you're gaining nothing by concatenating and only causing yourself more problems.

How you *should* be doing it:

```cpp
// The changing value as a float
float gprmc=75832.293;
// Print the prefix
mySerial.print(F("$GPRMC,"));
// Pad the value with zeroes
if (gprmc < 10) mySerial.print(F("0"));
if (gprmc < 100) mySerial.print(F("0"));
if (gprmc < 1000) mySerial.print(F("0"));
if (gprmc < 10000) mySerial.print(F("0"));
if (gprmc < 100000) mySerial.print(F("0"));
// Print the value with 3 decimal places
mySerial.print(gprmc, 3);
// Finally print the suffix
mySerial.println(F(",A,4042.695,N,07400.796,W,,,080120,000.0,W*63"));
```

Note the use of the `F()` macro to further reduce RAM usage by keeping the string constants in flash memory.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any difference on how the message will be transmitted by using mySerial.print(...) or mySerial.write(...)? somehow, the [example](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/RS232_Shield/) uses the .write() command, which introduced my problems.

Comment: No. `print` just calls `write` but accepts more parameter types.